# Custom numeric format string to always display the sign

Tags: c#, .net, formatting, string-formatting

Is there any way I can specify a standard or custom numeric format string to always output the sign, be it +ve or -ve (although what it should do for zero, I'm not sure!)

Answer (score 363, accepted):

Yes, you can. 
There is conditional formatting. See [Conditional formatting in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx)

eg:

```
string MyString = number.ToString("+0;-#");
```

Where each section separated by a semicolon represents positive and negative numbers

or:

```
string MyString = number.ToString("+#;-#;0");
```

if you don't want the zero to have a plus sign.

Comment: Fixed a bug whereby negatives did not get a minus.

Comment: Thanks you so much! I have been busting my head for like an hour to figure out what's the equivalent of the '+'-flag of printf in C# and you gave me THE answer.

Comment: with `+#;-#`, for the value 0 I get just "+", with no actual 0. for me I want 0 to appear as "+0", so this works: `+#;-#;+0`.

Comment: Thanks! Mixing this with `''` will do great things! Look at this: `Changes.ToString("'('#' ▲)';'('#' ▼)';''")` ! It saved me lots of time and hundreds of `if` statements! :)

Comment: @orionelenzil I had the same problem. You could also do ```+0;-#``` instead of ```+#;-#;+0``` This answer was really misleading for me.

Comment: @Shahab I like it. Note that you don't even have to display the numeric value of the number with the controlling sign if you don't want to... `string msg = $"The stock market is {delta:▲;▼;~} today.";`.

Comment: This doesn't work for number with decimals.

Answer (score 61):

Beware, when using conditional formatting the negative value doesn't automatically get a sign. You need to do

```
string MyString = number.ToString("+#;-#;0");
```

Comment: As others pointed out, `+0;-#` gives you the same result with cleaner code.

Answer (score 52):

You can also use format strings in string.Format(); the format string is separated from the index with a colon (':')

```
var f = string.Format("{0}, Force sign {0:+#;-#;+0}, No sign for zero {0:+#;-#;0}", number);
```

For number { +1, -1, 0 } this gives:

> 1, Force sign +1, No sign for zero +1
>   -1, Force sign -1, No sign for zero -1
>   0, Force sign +0, No sign for zero 0

You can also use an interpolated string instead of `string.Format` to obtain the same result:

```
var f = $"{number}, Force sign {number:+#;-#;+0}, No sign for zero {number:+#;-#;0}";
```

Comment: Last line of your answer should say "Default format 0, Force sign +, No sign for zero 0." because that's the actual result of ```+#;-#``` format for value 0

Comment: Thank you, Kamil - I missed that. I have now corrected the force sign format: +#;-#;+0 (instead of +#;-#)

Comment: You can get the force sign behavior with a simpler format: `+0;-#`. :)

Comment: @Andrew, Indeed, but I prefer `+#;-#;+0` over `+#;-#` as this makes it clearer that 0 will be formatted as +0

Answer (score 15):

Contrary to the other answers it seems that if you want to get +1, -1, +0 (for arguments 1, -1, 0) you need to use the format:

```
String.Format("{0:+#;-#;+0}", 0));  // output: +0
```

or

```
String.Format("{0:+0;-#}", 0));  // output: +0
```

If you use just `+#;-#` it will display just `+` (not `+0`) for 0.

**The "#" Custom Specifier** (at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx)

> Note that this specifier never displays a zero that is not a significant digit, even if zero is the only digit in the string. It will display zero only if it is a significant digit in the number that is being displayed.

Also please keep in mind that if you need any decimal precision you need to specify it like that:

```
String.Format("{0:+0.##;-#.##}", 0));  // output: +0
```

or, if you wan't zeros to always show up, like that:

```
String.Format("{0:+0.00;-#.00}", 0));  // output: +0.00
```

Answer (score 1):

For a numeric expression of any type:

```
+###,###,###,###,###,###,###,###,###,##0.###,###,###,###,###,###,###,###,###,###;-###,###,###,###,###,###,###,###,###,##0.###,###,###,###,###,###,###,###,###,###;0
```

Use three parts for three cases: positive;negative;zero

Other aspects of the example:

- Zero is not signed. You could have it show as anything, such as "zero".
- Absolute values less than one have a leading 0 before the decimal point. Adjust to taste.
- Number of digits is for the largest and smallest absolute decimal values. Adjust to taste.
- Decimal point character is culture-specific. .NET substitutes.
- Grouping separators are optional. The character is culture-specific. .NET substitutes. (The positions are also culture-specific but that's only controlled by your format string.) You also use any other character except the special characters for Format (which include , . # 0).

Comment: A format of `#,##0` is sufficient for any number of thousands separators.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment so i Do an answer here (nuts reputation system ....)

You can Use number.ToString("+0;-#") very well to Produce the UTC String TimeFormat

Here showed in PowerShell code

```
"$([System.DateTime]::Now.ToString('HH:mm:ss.fff'))$($([System.TimeZoneInfo]::Local.GetUtcOffset([System.DateTime]::Now).TotalMinutes.ToString('+0;-#')))"
```

Thank you @gcores https://stackoverflow.com/users/40256/gcores