# C# Double.ToString()

Tags: c#, double, string-formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Custom numeric format string to always display the sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348201/custom-numeric-format-string-to-always-display-the-sign)

To format a double to certain precision in C# I write this:

```
d.ToString("#0.00");
```

What if I want to force a the sign to appear..
e.g
+2.54  and -2.54

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work.

```
YourDoublenumber.ToString("+#;#");
```