# How to force a sign when formatting an Int in c#

Tags: c#, tostring

I want to format an integer i (`-100 < i < 100`), such that:

-99  formats as "-99"
9  formats as "+09"
-1 formats as "-01"
0 formats as "+00"

```
i.ToString("00")
```

is close but does not add the + sign when the int is positive.

Is there any way to do this without explicit distinguishing between
`i >= 0` and `i < 0`?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/348201/custom-numeric-format-string-to-always-display-the-sign

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom numeric format string to always display the sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348201/custom-numeric-format-string-to-always-display-the-sign)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try this:

```cs
i.ToString("+00;-00;+00");
```

When separated by a semicolon (;) the first section will apply to positive values, the second section will apply to negative values, the third section will apply to zero (0).

Note that the third section can be omitted if you want zero to be formatted the same way as positive numbers.  The second section can also be omitted if you want negatives formatted the same as positives, but want a different format for zero.

Reference: [MSDN Custom Numeric Format Strings: The ";" Section Separator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings)

Comment: The OP wants `0` to display as "+00", not plain "00".

Comment: It seems that `i.ToString("+00;-00");` is enough. 0 is considered positive here.

Comment: How can the first section apply to positive values *and zero*, and the third section apply to zero? How do you know what actually gets applied to zero with that logic?

Comment: @itsme86 7 years and nobody noticed that...  Thanks, I updated that bit.

Answer (score 4):

You might be able to do it with a format string like so..

```
i.ToString("+00;-00");
```

This would produce the following output..

```
2.ToString("+00;-00");    // +02
(-2).ToString("+00;-00"); // -02
0.ToString("+00;-00");    // +00
```

Take a look at the [MSDN documentation for Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx)

Comment: The OP wants `0` to display as "+00", not plain "00".

Comment: @LukeH You are right, my mistake, modified answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
i.ToString("+00;-00");
```

Some examples:

```
Console.WriteLine((-99).ToString("+00;-00"));    // -99
Console.WriteLine(9.ToString("+00;-00"));        // +09
Console.WriteLine((-1).ToString("+00;-00"));     // -01
Console.WriteLine((0).ToString("+00;-00"));      // +00
```