# signed numbers + or -

Tags: c#, string-formatting, sign

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to force a sign when formatting an Int in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301201/how-to-force-a-sign-when-formatting-an-int-in-c-sharp)
>   [Format number with + and - sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9782131/format-number-with-and-sign)

I would like to sign numbers when there are positive or negative (c#):

```
text = cname + " " + String.Format("{0:0.#}", move) + "%  , \n " + text;
```

I want for positive numbers a format like "+2.5%".
Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Format number with + and - sign](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9782131/format-number-with-and-sign) or [How to force a sign when formatting an Int in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301201/how-to-force-a-sign-when-formatting-an-int-in-c-sharp)

Comment: read msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check on MSDN : [**Format Number To Display**](http://pranayamr.blogspot.in/2012/06/format-number-to-display.html)

```
string MyString = number.ToString("+#;-#;0");
```

`; - Section separator` - Defines sections with separate format strings for **positive, negative, and zero numbers**.