# Format for displaying float?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, devexpress

I need to display float numerics with symbol "+" or "-" before.

What is the correct string format?

For ex.

```
-1,5
-1
-0,5
 0
+0,5
+1
```

```
  settings.Columns.Add(column =>
          {
              column.FieldName = "current";
              column.Caption = "Numeric";
              column.ColumnType = MVCxGridViewColumnType.SpinEdit;
              var edsettings = column.PropertiesEdit as DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors.SpinEditProperties;
              edsettings.DisplayFormatString = "0.#";
          });
```

this is column of devexpress component grid in asp.mvc. where "current" is decimal value in Model

Comment: Can you post any sample code?

Comment: Try `"+0.#;-0.#"` or `"+#.00;-#.00"`

Comment: please improve your question by given some more details

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom numeric format string to always display the sign](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/348201/custom-numeric-format-string-to-always-display-the-sign)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the semicolon seperator to define different formats for positive and negative values, for example

`string.Format("{0:+0.0;-0.0}", floatValue)`

If you don't want to have a sign before a zero, then use a third option:

`edsettings.DisplayFormatString = "+0.#;-0.#;0";`

Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx#SectionSeparator