# Sign and 0 in front of double

Tags: c#, count, double, sign, digits

I need some mechanism to count numbers from

-178.125 through -1.875 and +000.000 to +180.000 with step 1.875

so it always has plus or minus sign in the front of the number and has three digits, then dot and then three digits again.

The only thing that comes to my mind is a lot of if conditions.

The best for me is solution in C#.

Thank you

Edit:

I need some while cycle like

```
N = -178.125;
while(n != +180.000)
{
...
N += 1.875
}
```

And i want the N to go like -178.125, ..., -001.875, +000.000, +001.875,... +180.000

Is this understandable? :D I know I have troubles with specifying things :)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Provide your code and exact problem.

Comment: Im having trouble understanding what exactly you need help with, can you try clarifying?

Comment: for loop starting at -178.125 incrementing by 1.875 up to 180.000 comes to mind using a decimal as the type. Custom/conditional formatting should take care of the output. See this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348201/custom-numeric-format-string-to-always-display-the-sign

Comment: A list of things you want is not a question. What's your question?

Comment: My question is, can you make some counting like in cycle from number -178.125, through +000.000, to +180.000? The main problem is to have the format three digits, then dot and then three digits again, plus the sign in front of the number (whether its plus or minus).

Comment: Thanks PaulF, it works. Now only to set the number of zeros before and after the number :)

Comment: You can use format specifiers to set the number of leading zeros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, this would be your way to go:

C#-Code

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    public class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        { 
            double a = -178.125;
            double aBound = -1.875;
            double b = 0.000;
            double bBound = 180.000;
            double inc = 1.875;

            // counts from a to aBound (-178.125 to -1.875) and prints the values to console
            Console.WriteLine(a);
            while (a < aBound)
            {
                a += inc;
                Console.WriteLine(a);
            }

            // counts from b to bBound (0.000 to 180.000) and prints the values to console
            Console.WriteLine("+" + b);
            while (b < bBound)
            {
                b += inc;
                Console.WriteLine("+" + b);
            }

            Console.Read();
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats great, and can in the second while cycle the number be with the sign plus, eg. +000.000, +001.875 and so on?

Comment: Sure. I modified my answer for you.

Comment: Thank you, that got me closer. :)

Comment: This is in general a bad practice because *float representation error accumulates on repeated additions*. The better technique is to replace the loops with `for (int i = 0; i < 96; ++i) { b = inc * i; ... }`  That way the representation error stays the same on every operation, rather than growing larger on each subsequent operation. (For this specific case the representation error is zero, so it's not a problem. But with other increments, it could be.)

Comment: If his question would have had general purpose, I would be with you. In this specific case I don't understand your downvote. Anyways, thanks for your reply.