# How to print a double with its sign?

Tags: c#

Hi I would print a double with its sign in C#. Is that possible?

```
     double x=+3;
     Console.WriteLine(x);
```

I want it to be displayed as "+3"

Comment: Possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/348242/7644018)

Comment: @PaulT. Thanks it worked <3