# C# Renaming a lot of files using formatted strings based on calculations

Tags: c#, math, numbers

I am working on modding the game Train Simulator and one of the tasks I've got into is renaming files and their contents for the routes used in the game. All the files used having codes that tells the game what objects should be placed where etc.

The first step that I am asking here is to rename the files themselves. The files are arranged like a coordinate-system, like this:
[List of files name +000000+000000.bin and counting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ahXC.jpg)
As you can see, the files are úsing a 6-digit numbers and starts with a + or - in the beginning like an XY-grid, relative to a point. My goal here is to mathematically increase or decrease the numbers in the XY-grid and make sure all the files are renamed according to the input provided by the user.

EDIT: The user would be moving point 0 somewehere else. if the file +000000+000000.bin should be renamed +000025-000067 then file +000000+000001.bin should be renamed +000025-000066.bin, -000003-000006-bin should be +000022-000070.bin and so on, by adding 25 in the first half and removing -67 from the other half of the filename.

Comment: @Blindy That's a pretty rude way of putting things, but the question is quite unclear.

Comment: @SummerADDE "Math" could be about anything. Could you elaborate a little more? Shall the user be able to translate coords? Warp? Scale? Rotate? ...

Comment: He just wants to increase or decrease. Math is a silly tag. The trick is in number [formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx).. - [Examples](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjLkfCfxrPpAhVNsKQKHRxbDOYQFjAAegQICRAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F348201%2Fcustom-numeric-format-string-to-always-display-the-sign&usg=AOvVaw3ZORxdSLbL91l5VwXryh7p)

Comment: The user would be moving point 0 somewehere else. if the file +000000+000000.bin should be renamed +000025-000067 then file +000000+000001.bin should be renamed +000025-000066.bin, -000003-000006-bin should be +000022-000070.bin and so on, by adding 25 in the first half and removing -67 from the other half of the filename.

Comment: @SummerADDE Welcome to the community! Can you please edit the title to be more descriptive to the task you are trying to achieve. Realistically this question is about string formatting based on numbers and parsing of strings to numbers, so an appropriate title would be "C# Renaming a lot of files using formatted strings based on calculations". And please ignore the negative comments, this community is about people helping people and those comments are not common and not appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Some pointers to get you started:

1. List all the files. See the [GetFiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=netcore-3.1) method.
2. Split the filename into the x and y coordinates. See [Substring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netcore-3.1)
3. Parse the x and y coordinates. See [Parse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netcore-3.1)
4. Apply offset to x and y coordinates, I hope you will manage this.
5. Format the new filename, See [String.Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=netcore-3.1) , [format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings) and [Include sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348201/custom-numeric-format-string-to-always-display-the-sign)
6. Finally, [Rename the file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.filesystem.renamefile?view=netcore-3.1)

This should give enough information to start to make a solution.