# Can I display float as percent value with positive/negative sign just with formatting string?

Tags: c#, string-formatting

For example, input 0.12 should produce string "+12%" and -0.42 should produce "-42%". I'd like to achieve it without writing any actual code, only by defining format string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom numeric format string to always display the sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348201/custom-numeric-format-string-to-always-display-the-sign)

Comment: Not exactly. I wanted to know specifically format that would both change decimal value to percent and provide a sign. I've seen suggested question but coudn't deduce solution from it.

Comment: Well haven't you got your answer, both below and on that other question: format string `+#;-#;0` will do the trick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use conditional string formating:

```
public static void Main()
{
    string format = "+#.00 %;-#.00 %;+0.00 %";
    Console.WriteLine((-0.12).ToString(format));
    Console.WriteLine((0.12).ToString(format));
    Console.WriteLine(0.ToString(format));
}
```

which outputs:

```
-12.00 %
+12.00 %
+0.00 %
```

Unfortunately there is no value for [PercentPositivePattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.percentpositivepattern?view=net-6.0)  that allows to specify a plus sign application wide.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

namespace PercentageTest {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            double number = 0.12;
            Console.WriteLine("The percent format is as : +" + number.ToString("P", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
            double no = 0.04;
            Console.WriteLine("The percent format is as : +" + no.ToString("P", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
            double negNumber = -0.12;
            Console.WriteLine("The percent format is as : " + negNumber.ToString("P", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        }
    }
}
```

You can play with it here:
[code here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgNAJiA1AHwAICYCMBYAUKgBgAIjVMA6AcQBsB7AIwENqBLAL0eBdqgG488URgFsApgGcADowDGoogAVRYOVGCMA5qIAqE4EQDeeEiQylMAdkPGTtsgDZSAFiIBZRiygAKMgQDaALpEjGAa4gCU1ri2MSZwtBD01PJQEML0ykQAvEQE5Jjo/NGxMWQAnF4ARNoAFvKSyqr6AGa0YMKcRCziwT0gRJVEiESp6crk2rQAysBgnhpVCpUwRADCENTAEGCiAJJQreT7AG4hLIxq65vbouHhRSUx8YnJI7TZueQETg+PJuVVWr1RqiNREVrtTrdXpEfqDYZQWgTaazeaLZZrDZbHb7Q4nM4XYBXbG3e42P5EZ5JFKiDQAOTSGTAHwAtHkCr8KQDqnUiA0VKCWm0OvpoYw+gMhiNaQyxmBkTM5lAFpUlitiTdcUj8XNCRqdndOTEAL7koim3DGoA==)

Comment: For 0.12 this solution produces output "12.00 %" without positive sign "+" at the beginnig.

Comment: @PrzemekNowaczyk unfortunately there is no built-in possibility for the "+", you can do it via concatenating the strings:
`Console.WriteLine("The percent format is as : +" + number.ToString("P", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));`

Answer (score 0):

You could use extension method :

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string ToPercentage(this double number)
    {
        number *= 100; 
        return $"{(number >= 0 ? '+' : "")}{number:N}%";            
    }
}
```

usage example :

```
double number = 0.95;
string str = number.ToPercentage(); // output +95%
        
double number2 = -0.15;
string str2 = number2.ToPercentage(); // output -15%
```