# How to format integer value as string with symbol "+" if its positive in C#?

Tags: c#, integer, tostring

I want to print values as "+ 10 %" and "- 10 %".

For percentage I use `myValue.ToString("P0")` and its output is: **10 %**, **- 10 %**.

How to add **"+"** symbol to that?

Thanks a lot

Comment: `var val = myValue.ToString("P0"); if(!val.StartsWith('-')) val = $"+ {val}";`

Comment: `Console.WriteLine($"{myValue:+ #;- #;0} %");`  assuming the spaces were intentional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The options available are at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#PFormatString

There is a `NegativeSign` option to change the negative symbol, but not the positive one, so in that case you will have to fall back to having your own conditional code to use the `P0` format, or multiply your value by 100 and use a conditional format specifier as described in the answer linked in the comments, [Custom numeric format string to always display the sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348201/custom-numeric-format-string-to-always-display-the-sign) .

Comment: yes, commented link helped thanks